# Convergence of $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin(n)}{n!} $

Tags: calculus

I have tried using the integral test but it does not work, since the integral test require the series to be a continuous, positive, decreasing function. I tried using the comparison test to compare it with $\frac{\sin n}{n}$ but it doesn't seem to help. May  I know what test I should use?

Comment: $|\sin n| \leq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Initially, I left an answer that fed off of your comment and suggested comparing the series against the corresponding series for $e^1$.  However, I have deleted this answer as non-rigorous.  The posted series can not be construed to be an alternating series, or a strictly increasing series.  Therefore, it seems to me that the question is still in doubt, despite your comment.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent so would not be useful for a comparison.

Comment: @Henry Do you agree that comparison against $e^1$ is not immediately decisive?

Comment: The series is absolutely convergent and the answer you wrote is absolutely correct. Why did you delete it? @user2661923

Comment: @user2661923 Do you know that absolutely convergent series are convergent?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I re-instituted the answer.  I think that my analysis as originally posted was invalid, but is now valid.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If by absolutely convergent series, you mean that if, regardless of whether the series is alternating or not, the series formed by the absolute value of the terms is convergent, then the original series is convergent - No, I didn't originally know that - however, I just figured it out on the fly.

Comment: @user2661923 $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n!}$ is absolutely convergent so $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin(n)}{n!}$ is too

Comment: @Henry Yes, I realize that now.  However, I didn't realize it when I first posted an answer.  Nor was I aware that this was a well known theorem in Real Analysis.  I knew about a related theorem re (strictly) alternating series.  But the posted series is not strictly alternating, which threw me.

Comment: Also, note that $n!\gt n^2$ for all $n\ge 4$ so $|\frac{\sin n}{n!}|\le \frac 1{n!}\le \frac 1{n^2}$  for all $n\ge 4$ and hence by comparison test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{\sin n}{n!}| $is convergent. Now what do you know about absolute convergent series?

Answer (score -4):

Per the comment of
Kavi Rama Murthy, compare the series against

$\displaystyle e^1 = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdots.$

**Edit** 
Everything below the horizontal line, represents my personal thought process, for this answer.

Should be noted that (I was unaware that) if you have a series $\sum a_n$, and $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent, then $\sum a_n$ is also convergent.  Apparently, this is a standard result in Real Analysis, which is immediately decisive.  My following analysis simply reflects that I was unaware of this.

---

**Edit**
It actually seems to me that the issue is moderately more complicated.

Let $S$ denote the sum of all of the non-negative terms of the series and let $T$ denote the sum of all of the negative terms of the series.

By comparison against $e^1$ it is clear that both $S$ and $|T|$ are strictly increasing convergent series.  Therefore, the finite sum $S - |T|$ must exist.

Comment: And we can compute easily the infinite sum

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Really? Hard to imagine using an altered form of the Taylor Series for the sine function (with $n!$ inserted as an added factor in the denominator).  Agreed, that given $n$ you can determine the sign of $\sin(n)$, but using that determination to compute the overall sum seems difficult to me.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sin%28n%29+%2F+%28n%21%29) says $\sin(\sin(1)) (\sinh(\cos(1)) + \cosh(\cos(1)))\approx1.2799$

Comment: Use  $A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n!}=-1+e^{e^i}$ so $\Im(A)=\sin (\sin (1)) e^{\cos (1)}$

Comment: @Henry. Simplify to use less characters. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici "And we can compute easily the infinite sum".  It seems reasonable to presume that the OP (i.e. original poster) is untrained in Complex Analysis.  Personally, I don't see any Real Analysis approach to analytically computing the limit of the series, where computer software such as Wolfram Alpha is considered out of bounds.

Comment: This was just a comment for yourself only.